# Probability of failure of Uniform Sampling

Tags: probability, distributions, sampling, uniform-distribution, resampling

Say I have a bag with 10 numbered balls, and I pick one ball at each time step and then put it back in the bag. Since each ball is equally likely, therefore the current situation represents a uniform sampling with replacement scenario.
Say I repeat the above sampling with replacement step 1000 times. So in expectation, each ball should be picked 100 times.

But, in real experiments, it is also possible that some balls are picked much fewer times. Say ball numbered 5 is picked only 5 times instead of 100.

I am not sure how to calculate the probability of the event when some balls are rarely picked during uniform sampling? Any leads would be helpful.

Comment: Have you looked at our threads about [chi squared tests](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=chi+squared+test+is%3Aanswer+score%3A5)?

Comment: You appear to have edited your question (which is great) and reposted it (which is not).  Please don't do that: keep one question in one thread and edit it until you are satisfied.  Read our [help] for more information about how this site works.